# Is there an Annotation for member/method to be used by reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a method that is invoked by the same class using reflection.

I'd like to make the method private, but get a warning by the IDE that the method is not being used.

Well, it is being used - using reflection.

What annotations are there to indicate that a member/method is being used by reflection?

Comment: As i know there is no Special annotations, But you can use @SuppressWarnings("unused")

Comment: Not exactly what your'e asking for, but for something like that I'll often just use `@SuppressWarnings("unused") // used by reflection`.

Comment: If you’re talking about Eclipse, at least with the version I use, any custom annotation will do, I guess the (usually correct) assumption behind that behavior is that any annotation could add a semantic that supersedes the unused-method check.